# Python: scipy odeint stops integrating at maximum value and produces only half of intended plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, odeint

I am working on a piece of code which models the expansion of the universe, in particular I am integrating (using scipy odeint) the Friedmann equation to get a plot of the scale factor against time for different curvature. My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint

t_0 = 0.0004
a_0 = 0.001
omega_m = 1
omega_r = 0
omega_lambda = 0
omega_k = 1 - omega_lambda - omega_m - omega_r
H_0 = 1./13.799

def Friedmann(a, t):
    dadt = H_0 * (((omega_m) * a**(-1)) + ((omega_r) * a**(-2)) + ((omega_lambda) * a**2) + (omega_k))**(1./2.)
    return dadt

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1)

for omega_k in np.linspace(-1, 1, 3):
    t = np.linspace(t_0,50,200)
    a = odeint(Friedmann, a_0, t)
    a = np.array(a).flatten()
    ax.plot(t,a)

line1, = plt.plot(t, a, 'b')
plt.xlabel('Time/Gyr')
plt.ylabel('Scale factor a')
plt.grid(True)
plt.axis([0,50,0,5])
plt.show()
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqmPI.png) is the plot I get. I am trying to get a plot where the bottom (light blue) line loops back down and meets the x-axis at t ~ 43 Gyr but I can't seem to get this (maybe something to do with the integration).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Always report any errors or warnings that occur when you run your code.  In this case, did you notice this warning: `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  dadt = H_0 * (((omega_m) * a**(-1)) + ((omega_r) * a**(-2)) + ((omega_lambda) * a**2) + (omega_k))**(1./2.)` ?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Oh yes sorry I didn't even realise there was an error. I assume this happened due to the term in brackets turning negative at that value of t?

Comment: Yes. [Filler text to meet the minimum number of characters in a comment.]

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser is there a modulus function I can use to make the term in brackets always positive?

Comment: Do you mean something like [numpy.absolute](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html)?  (It has a shorter alias: `numpy.abs`.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I ended up using math.fabs but I’m still not getting the desired plot, I’ll have to do a bit more playing around